# My webpage is showing some apache tomcat error and not showing me the proper page of my website

Tags: jsp, tomcat

one of the apge in my website is not shown properly and it is showing an Apache Tomcat error and the content is as follows:

type Exception report

message

description:  The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:553)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

this is some part of code that i got as error while opening the jsp page. Please do help me out with this problem. Thank You.

Comment: You stopped at the most interesting bit. Read the root cause, then see what you can see in the JSP that might be the reason. Without seeing the root cause and the JSP in question, no-one can answer your question.

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332) org.apache.jsp.jsp.sectionsWindow1_jsp._jspService(sectionsWindow1_jsp.java:165) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.11 logs.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your JSP, you're calling `.nextToken()` without checking `.hasMoreTokens()`. This is the usual pattern (from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)):

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

If you just call `.nextToken()` without checking if a token is available, there will be times when you'll end up with the error you got.